# negative skew and positive medcouple

Tags: skewness, boxplot

I have below case where I see contradicting medcouple and skewness value :

[image]

Now, from the box plot, it is clear that the data has negative skewness but the medcouple shows slight positive skewness.

Am I missing any concept?

Comment: Maybe missing the fact that medcouple is a robust measure? You can remove the three outliers to the left and recompute the skewness.